# How to add IK to FK snap button in Rigify

Tags: rigging, armature, rigify

The rig that I'm using currently only has FK>IK snap, [image]

how do I get the opposite button, snapping IK controls to FK controls' position? Or not the button but do it in any other way?
Thx

[image]

Comment: Hi. It would be helpful if you could explain how you got the FK->IK key in the first place. I guess it's a Rigify type?

Comment: Ye it's created automatically in Rigify rigs when u generate them (provided there are IK controls in them). The are presets for different body parts etc, and this particular one only has one way snap button, without the second one, like meta human rig for example

Comment: You're obviously in pose mode and have selected a bone in an IK chain or the related FK chain.  In that case, the IK-FK snap switch should be immediately below the bit in your screen shot.  However, "Bone" is not a name that rigify usually uses.  Have you modified either the meta rig before generation, or the generated rig?  Because this looks like a failure to generate.  Can you add a Blend file of just your two rigs to your question that shows the problem? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: It's not a pre-built meta rig, I made a chain and applied tentacle rigify type to the first bone of it  There's 3 tentacle presets, only spline type has IK controls, but the IK to FK snap doesn't seem to be working... Is there a way I can do that manually maybe? If I switch to FK to change shape a bit I can't put IK cntrls to the new shape anymore... Here I made example blend-exchange.com/b/QlMDP61l